# Dependent expressions in a moongose query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this scenario where I need to pull from the database only the elements that have changed for a period of time.

I got a property as objectId that gets updated every time an element gets updated in the database.

I need to sync the data in the client (local storage) vs the data in the server (MongoDB), for that purpose I send a key value pair array from the client with the Id and changeset (another Id it could be a date or a hash); I want to query the elements within that array by id but only the ones that have a different changeset.

**Edit:**

The data structure is an array of objects:

```
[ 
     { 
         _id: '55396c4686f01367473c11e6', 
         hash:'554a4c1790146fc1188f175f' 
     }
]
```

but I splitted the list of objects in two simple arrays

```
ids = [ '55396c4686f01367473c11e6', '...','etc etc']
```

and the same for hash.

the issue is that I have no Idea to create a query that includes the a key-value pair into an expression, the query should be like:

> select an element which contains this id but it's hash is different to
>   thisone

```
var syncElements = function(data, callback){
    Element.find(
        { $and:[
            {_id:{$in:ids}} //--> how can I link the two expressions here? any other idead.
            ]
        ).exec().then(function(result2){
        callback({data: r});
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example that includes sample `data` and docs and expected output?

Comment: Hey @JohnnyHK I updated my question, I know that is going to be a piece of cake for you!  thanks for the help!